# /dev/sdb not showing up

Tags: partitioning, mount, ubuntu-studio

I am currently using Ubuntu Studio, and get this output whenever I use sudo fdisk -l :

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 61.96 MiB, 64970752 bytes, 126896 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 163.29 MiB, 171225088 bytes, 334424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 400.8 MiB, 420265984 bytes, 820832 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 91.69 MiB, 96141312 bytes, 187776 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 46.96 MiB, 49242112 bytes, 96176 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 55.56 MiB, 58261504 bytes, 113792 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 169.42 MiB, 177647616 bytes, 346968 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: Micron_2210_MTFDHBA512QFD               
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 18BF5EC6-BA94-4E61-BCC3-0B603B2CC137

Device              Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1       2048     534527    532480   260M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2     534528     567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3     567296  393915022 393347727 187.6G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4  393916416  394964991   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p5  394964992  395579391    614400   300M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p6  395579392  477499391  81920000  39.1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p7  823224320  824862718   1638399   800M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p8  824866816  953579519 128712704  61.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p9  953581568  955219966   1638399   800M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p10 955222016  956860414   1638399   800M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p11 956862464  958910463   2048000  1000M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p12 958910464  999804927  40894464  19.5G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p13 999804928 1000214527    409600   200M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p14 477499392  493883391  16384000   7.8G Linux swap
/dev/nvme0n1p15 493883392  637243391 143360000  68.4G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p16 637243392  638291967   1048576   512M EFI System

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/loop8: 164.76 MiB, 172761088 bytes, 337424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 70.41 MiB, 73834496 bytes, 144208 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop10: 345.03 MiB, 361791488 bytes, 706624 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop11: 47.99 MiB, 50323456 bytes, 98288 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop12: 63.22 MiB, 66293760 bytes, 129480 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop13: 176.88 MiB, 185466880 bytes, 362240 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop14: 346.3 MiB, 363118592 bytes, 709216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

But /dev/sdb seems to be absent, and I am unable to mount my Windows partition.

Comment: What is `/dev/sdb`? Why do you think it exists on your system? More importantly, what have you done to get to this point? You seem to have multiple EFI partitions and multiple "Microsoft basic data" partitions. Do you have multiple Windows installations? One of the "Microsoft basic data" partitions will be the Windows you are looking for.

Comment: Loops are normally 'snap'-applications. And it seems that you only have 1 nvme drive. Do you have another SSD drive in your computer? If so, is it connected correctly?

Comment: I have never seen so many ESP - efi system partitions. Many UEFI only allow one per device. UEFI spec does allow more than one, but not really required. p1 should be your only ESP. Not sure if you have boot files in any of the other ESP, as you should delete them, but may need to update boot first. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I have only one SSD and windows installation, maybe the partitions are because of various drives created in  windows? As for the EFI partitions, I've installed various other distros in the past, so maybe the EFI partitions for those were not deleted.

Comment: OK, then if you only have one SSD, there is no `/dev/sdb`. One drive means only `/dev/sda` or, as in your case where you have NVMe drives, `/dev/nvme0*`.

Comment: Okay, thanks. So would that mean that all the commands that are being used for /dev/sdb should be used for /dev/nvme0n1 ?